# initialize cv::Mat::ones with defined Size of type int

Tags: c++, opencv

I just started working with opencv and I just have some kind of basic question. I have an integer which is defined with patch_size * patch_size.

I created a Matrix cv::Mat::ones() and want to initialize this Matrix in first parameter (Size size) with Size of this patch_size * patch_size. But I am not able to convert/cast an Integer into Size.

So my question is, what is a good way to do this.

I also want to know, how I can define the second parameter (int type) in this case

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's built in: `cv::Mat mm = cv::Mat::ones(width, height, cv::CV_32S)`

Comment: thank you very much :) could you please tell me for what type CV_32S is good for? THX

Comment: `CV_32S` means signed integer, as usual `int`. I've never got to use it though.